# How do I set System and Application folder names for CodeIgniter project that is shared over GitHub?

Tags: git, codeigniter, github

I am working on a PHP project using CodeIgniter with a friend. Whenever we merge one of our branches, the System and Application file paths are specific to our own machines. Example:

```
    $system_path = '/Users/otherGuy/Documents/Aptana/Systems-A-D-Project-Code/code_igniter/system';

    $application_folder = '/Users/otherGuy/Documents/Aptana/Systems-A-D-Project-Code/code_igniter/application';
```

We are both testing on our local environments. What can we do to standardize this path so that one of us does not have to change the paths when the other merges their branch?

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding config.php to gitignore if you can manually deploy in your integration.

a better solution would be to evaluate why you need the full path in the config.

why does

```
$system_path = 'system';
```

not work?

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me, sorry it's been a while. What does 'system' reference? Is that something that will automatically point to my machine?